# jQuery render to pdf

Tags: jquery, html, css, jspdf

I got a bit of an issue with a Js script that I made, the idea behind this script is to render a specific div in HTML to CSS.

Currently its working and doing its job BUT not exactly like I want it, Currently it's only rendering the view of the screen and will only show the content in the pdf that the user is currently looking at this means it will cut off any content below or above that the user's screen that is currently not showing.

Is there a way to set it so it doesn't take the viewpoint and instead it takes the content in the div and renders that out? This happens on HTML docs with lots of content (of course)

And it renders white backgrounds as black for some unknown reason.

**Sample Code**

```js
$('#print').click(function() {

    var w = document.getElementById("content").offsetWidth;
    var h = document.getElementById("content").offsetHeight;
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("content"), {
      dpi: 300, // Set to 300 DPI
      scale: 3, // Adjusts your resolution
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1);
        var doc = new jsPDF('L', 'px', [w, h]);
        doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 0, 0, w, h);
        doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
body {
    background: beige;
  }
  
  header {
    background: red;
  }
  
  footer {
    background: blue;
  }
  
  #content {
    background: yellow;
    width: 70%;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    padding: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.min.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <h1>WorLD HellO</h1>
            <h3>Hello WOrld</h3>
        </div>
        <center>
            <button id="print">Click for PDF</button>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Edit**

I found a workaround for the issues I had but still trying to figure out how to set the quality and as well as removing unnecessary white space around the document.

Here is the Js snippet so far

```
    function getPDF() {

            var HTML_Width = $(".canvas_div_pdf").width();
            var HTML_Height = $(".canvas_div_pdf").height();
            var top_left_margin = 15;
            var PDF_Width = HTML_Width + (top_left_margin * 2);
            var PDF_Height = (PDF_Width * 1.5) + (top_left_margin * 2);
            var canvas_image_width = HTML_Width;
            var canvas_image_height = HTML_Height;

            var totalPDFPages = Math.ceil(HTML_Height / PDF_Height) - 1;


            html2canvas($(".canvas_div_pdf")[0], {
                allowTaint: true
            }).then(function (canvas) {
                canvas.getContext('2d');

                console.log(canvas.height + "  " + canvas.width);


                var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
                var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', [PDF_Width, PDF_Height]);
                pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPG', top_left_margin, top_left_margin, canvas_image_width,
                    canvas_image_height);


                for (var i = 1; i <= totalPDFPages; i++) {
                    pdf.addPage(PDF_Width, PDF_Height);
                    pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPG', top_left_margin, -(PDF_Height * i) + (top_left_margin * 4),
                        canvas_image_width, canvas_image_height);
                }

                pdf.save("HTML-Document.pdf");
            });
        };
```

If you want to use the above just add `onclick='getpdf()'` to your button

removing the black rendering, you need to set an Id or class to the div that you are tareting and give it a CSS Background color of #ffffff

Any help would be appreciated

Kind Regards,
Faz.

Comment: Why are trying to convert and HTML page to a canvas and then put that into a PDF? PDFs don't have resolution defined in pixels but inside as points (which are a fraction of an inch). By rasterizing your page and placing it in the PDF the size won't ever be representable to the actual size displayed on screen. That is to say if someone has a higher DPI screen, the image may be larger or smaller than it originally was, which can also cause pixelation. I'm wondering if there's a reason you are trying to do this, and if so, what is that reason?

Comment: @Kyle I'm trying anything at the moment that's why and for now that js script worked but not very effectively. Like you said the resolution is a problem as well as the html2canvas doesn't print only the div specified but also white space around it (kind of annoying) and it doesn't print bullet points for some reason. The Idea behind this whole endeavour is that I'm busy making an online Resume that people can download via PDF format and as Resume's go it needs to look good. but going through this whole endeavour it's quite painful. If you have any suggestions I would appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

The first issue you were having is that your unit was set to `px` and `jsPDF` was converting units on you. The primary document is always in `pt`, but when you supply the image `width`/`height`, `jsPDF` converts the pixels to points. I don't exactly know what their algorithm is, but if you change the unit to `pt` then the whole image is captured.

If I may, there are some recommendations I have on your code.

1. You're using an outdated version of html2canvas. You're using version `0.4.1` and the latest is `1.0.0-rc.5`. Although I had some issues with that version, `1.0.0-rc.1` seems to work for me.
2. You don't have to pass an image URI to `jsPDF`, you can pass the canvas element.

If the end result is a resume, they are usually letter sized. I would probably recommend designing your content using `pt`, `em`, `rem`, and `in` units. Although you will need to convert inches to 72dpi instead of the default 96dpi.

Here's a sandbox showing the usage of `to` instead of `px`: https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-blackburn-y093n

And here's an example I made showing how to make a simple resume and download the PDF: https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-austin-rzlc9

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey @kyle, Thanks I finally got it to render high-quality PDF's (18.5mb to be exact) going to play around with the DPI and see if I cant make the file size smaller. I added scale under the dpi to see if I cant eliminate any unnecessary whitespace that it is currently generating around the PNG in the PDF doc could be that my content is not set to em, rem in CSS that's causing this. but at least I'm on the right path.

Edit* do you know of a way to set it to fit to page or fill the entire PDF?

Comment: Another thing instead of PNG I used SVG and it works! Brings down the file size to 600kb with excellent quality

Comment: Found a bug, if you scroll to the bottom then it only captures the bottom section and creates a black (White space) rendered space beneath it....